# How can I query transactions from a particular month in my expense planner app

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I am working on expense planner app, and want to show the user transaction of each month separately. Please help how to query from the database. I have used Iso8601toString to insert date of transactions in the database. Please help as I am stuck. Finally, I want to display transactions of the last 13 months on a monthly basis. I have started learning for last 4 months.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:expense_planner/helpers/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:expense_planner/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Transactions with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [];

  List<Transaction> get userTransactions {
    return [..._userTransactions];
  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetTransactions() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('transactions');
    _userTransactions = dataList
        .map(
          (item) => Transaction(
            id: item['id'],
            title: item['title'],
            amount: item['amount'],
            // date: item['date'],
            date: DateTime.parse(item['date']),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addNewTransaction(
      String txTitle,
      double txAmount,
      DateTime chosenDate) async {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: chosenDate,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    DBHelper.insert('transactions', {
      'id': DateTime.now().toString(),**strong text**
      'title': newTx.title,
      'amount': newTx.amount,
      'date': newTx.date.toIso8601String(),
    });
    _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Future<Database> database() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'expense_planner.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE transactions(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, amount REAL, date 
           TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
  }

  static Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, Object> data) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    db.insert(
      table,
      data,
      conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(String table) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    return db.query(table);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sanjay. It seems that my question was not drafted properly. I want to display expenses of last 13 months (on monthly basis) say from 1 to 31st Jan and so on. Sorry for the inconvenience. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can compare and sort ISO8601 DateTimeStamp with a simple string comparison. You can read more about it [here](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-development/iso-8601/).
Please check the following example where I have created two buttons, one for showing all expenses and another for showing the last 6 months' expenses.
 You can easily modify it to show the last 13 months expenses

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

enum CustomDateRange { All, Last6Months }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CustomDateRange dateRange = CustomDateRange.All;

// data for testing
  List<Expense> sampleExpenses = [
    Expense(
        title: "Expense_A",
        amount: 1212.20,
        timeStamp: currentTimeInIso8601String()),
    Expense(
        title: "Expense_B",
        amount: 112.20,
        timeStamp:
            new DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 30)).toIso8601String()),
    Expense(
        title: "Expense_C",
        amount: 1312.20,
        timeStamp:
            new DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 60)).toIso8601String()),
    Expense(
        title: "Expense_D",
        amount: 1512.20,
        timeStamp:
            new DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 190)).toIso8601String()),
    Expense(
        title: "Expense_E",
        amount: 1512.20,
        timeStamp:
            new DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 190)).toIso8601String()),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Flutter SQLite")),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Expense>>(
        future: dateRange == CustomDateRange.All
            ? DBProvider.db.getAllExpenses()
            : DBProvider.db.getSpecificExpenses(
                DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 180)).toIso8601String(),
                DateTime.now().toIso8601String()),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Expense>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Expense item = snapshot.data[index];
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.title),
                    leading: Text(item.id.toString()),
                    trailing: Text(item.timeStamp.toString()));
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          Expense rnd = sampleExpenses[math.Random().nextInt(sampleExpenses.length)];
          await DBProvider.db.insertExpense(rnd);
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("All Data"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  dateRange = CustomDateRange.All;
                });
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Last 6 month Data"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  dateRange = CustomDateRange.Last6Months;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static String currentTimeInIso8601String() {
    var currentDateTime = (new DateTime.now()).toIso8601String();
    return currentDateTime;
  }
}

class Expense {
  int id = 0;
  String title = '';
  double amount = 0.0;
  String timeStamp = '';

  Expense({this.id, this.title, this.amount, this.timeStamp});

  factory Expense.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Expense(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        timeStamp: json["timeStamp"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "amount": amount,
        "timeStamp": timeStamp,
      };
}

class DBProvider {
  DBProvider._();

  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // if _database is null we instantiate it
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "TestDB.db");
    await deleteDatabase(path);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Expenses ("
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "title TEXT,"
          "amount REAL,"
          "timeStamp String"
          ")");
    });
  }

  Future<int> insertExpense(Expense expense) async {
    final db = await database;
    //get the biggest id in the table
    var table = await db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id)+1 as id FROM Expenses");
    int id = table.first["id"];
    //insert to the table using the new id
    var raw = await db.rawInsert(
        "INSERT Into Expenses (id,title,amount,timeStamp)"
        " VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
        [id, expense.title, expense.amount, expense.timeStamp]);
    return raw;
  }

  Future<List<Expense>> getAllExpenses() async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("Expenses");
    List<Expense> list =
        res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Expense.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
    return list;
  }

  Future<List<Expense>> getSpecificExpenses(
      String minDate, String maxDate) async {
    final db = await database;

    try {
      var res = await db.rawQuery(
          "SELECT * "
          "FROM Expenses "
          "WHERE timeStamp >= ? "
          "AND "
          "timeStamp <= ? ",
          [minDate, maxDate]);
      print(res.length);
      List<Expense> list =
          res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Expense.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
      return list;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return [];
  }
}
```